# Не получается открыть веб интерфейс Wildfly. По указанному IP Адресу не открывает, подскажите с чем это может быть связано?

Tags: centos7, wildfly, web-apps

Была предоставлена инструкция для развертки веб приложения через `Wildfly`.
Все пункты были выполнены,  после выполнения команды `standalone.sh` появилась ошибка:

> Этот адрес уже используется.

Предположили, что порт `8080` может быть занят. Самостоятельно освободили его - результат тот же самый

Пункт, после которого возникла данная проблема:
[image: пункт, после которого возникла данная проблема]

Терминал:
[image: терминал]

Прикрепила фотографию терминала, что получается после ввода команды `standalone.sh` и также прикрепила фотографию пункта после которого возникла данная проблема
Операционная система `CentOS 7`.

Подумали, если занят порт, то его нужно освободить, в итоге самостоятельно освободили - результата не дало. Далее пытались пробросить порты, но тоже не получилось.

Подумали, что `IP` адрес может быть заблокирован из-за частых попыток входа, с помощью команды `fail2ban` убедились, что это не так. В файле `standalone.conf` меняли адреса подключения на `0.0.0.0 / 127.0.0.1 /` и также указывали адрес сервера. Запустить `wildfly` не удалось, подскажите в чем может быть ошибка или проблема?

Comment: установите wildfly у себя. он не требователен к ресурсам.

Comment: Не очень поняла. Wildfly уже установлен на linux

Comment: в смысле на свою машинку

Comment: я подключилась к выделенному серверу по ssh и как установка wildfly на основной пк поможет в решение проблемы?

Comment: как вы можете найти ошибку в ошибочно установленном и ошибочно настроенном сервере, как не сравнив его с хотя бы рабочим сервером, установленным самостоятельно?

Comment: Wildfly стоит на CenteOS7, то есть проблема все таки лежит в установке, а не в чем то другом?

Comment: Плюс уже сравнивала с правильно установленной версией, в файлах все идентично

Comment: думаю. понимаете, что даже версия явы может дать неоднозначное поведение продукта. какое требование у вашей версии wildly? и какая версия установлена на centos7 (довольно старая версия )